# Why the shared memory I get in my thread is not good?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, shared-memory

I have a thread that display some data I have on my shared memory

```
void *display_map(void *data)
{
  struct s_case *map;
  int i;
  int j;
  int shm_id;

  while (1)
  {
    i = 0;
    shm_id = shmget(*(int *)data, WIDTH * HEIGHT * sizeof(struct s_case), SHM_R | SHM_W);
    map = shmat(shm_id, NULL, SHM_W | SHM_R);
    while (i < HEIGHT)
      {
        j = 0;
        while (j < WIDTH)
        {
          printf("%d", map[(i + 1) * j].nteam);
          j++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        i++;
      }
    printf("\033[H\033[J");
    usleep(10000);
  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Problem is, the data is display is not complete, some informations are missing.
When I print these informations in the last of my processes, all works fine.

`data` contains the key returned by `ftok`

Have an idea what I do wrong ?

Comment: The problem may be due to concurrency, but you didn't show us the code that populate the segment, etc. Access should be something like `(i*WIDTH)+j` to be correct, is that the problem ?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Maybe I have a problem with access too, but when I try to access the data in my last process the same way I did in the thread, it works fine.

Comment: Concurrency, if you use thread may I suspect that the reader is concurrent with the writer?

Comment: Yes, they are running at the same time. First I create my shared memory with `shm_id = shmget(key, WIDTH * HEIGHT * sizeof(struct s_case), IPC_CREAT | SHM_R | SHM_W);` then i launch my thread. After that I launch all my processes that write the data.

Comment: Then you cannot ensure that the writers finished before reader reads... It seems that you need to use some producer/consumer pattern.

Comment: You do know that you only need shared memory when sharing between processes?  For sharing between threads you can use any off-stack data area, like the heap (malloc).  You still need concurrency checks though.

Comment: @cdarke my goal is to get data from processes to my display thread.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov: in that case you will probably need to make sure that the processes are synchronised as well.  You will need to use a kernel object, probably semaphores (not all implementations of pthreads support cross-process mutexes).  Have you considered message queues instead?